# table of contents removes header and footer of page

Tags: table-of-contents, header-footer

First of all, I've only picked up LaTeX a couple of days ago so please excuse my ignorance.

I'm working on a report and I noticed that once I added a table of contents, the header and footer disappears from the page. You can see below how the header look like:

[image]

And the footer:

[image]

However, the header disappears on the table of contents page.

My .tex:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[margin=3cm]{geometry}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\usepackage[document]{ragged2e}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage{tocloft}


\setlength\headheight{26pt}
\rhead{\includegraphics[scale=0.15]{images/x.pdf}}
\lhead{\includegraphics[width=4cm]{images/y.jpg}}

\addtocontents{toc}{\vspace{1cm}}

\addto\captionsenglish{
    \renewcommand{\contentsname}
    {\LARGE Table of Contents}
}

\begin{document}

\setlength{\headsep}{3.5cm}
\centering
{\huge\bfseries Something something something\par}
\vspace{2cm}
{\huge Internship Report \par}
\vspace{2cm}
\renewcommand\baselinestretch{1.5}\Large\bfseries
{
    John Doe \linebreak
    12345678
}
\par
\vspace{2cm}
\renewcommand\baselinestretch{1.5}\Large\normalfont
{ 
    Advisors: \linebreak
    Jane Doe \(|\)  ISEC \linebreak
    John Doe \(|\) GoodBarber
}
\par
\vspace{2cm}
\renewcommand\baselinestretch{1.5}\Large\normalfont
{ 
    Bachelor in John Doing \linebreak
    Jane Doe Branch \linebreak
    Polytechnic Institute of John Doe \linebreak
    Institute of John Doe \linebreak
    June 2021
}

\newpage 
\ % The empty page
\thispagestyle{empty}
\clearpage
\newpage
\setlength{\headsep}{1cm}

\setlength{\cftbeforetoctitleskip}{-3em}

\tableofcontents
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}

\end{document}
```

Can you spot the mistake?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: it is much easier to debug if you provide an example that shows the problem. You posted code in a form that can't be used and using commands such as \cftbeforetoctitleskip that are not defined.

Comment: you can use `example-image` as that is available for tests, and make a self-contained small but complete document.

Comment: Sorry. I updated the code so you can try it out in you editor.

Comment: if I add `[draft]` to graphicx so I get no error for the missing images I get the  warning Package fancyhdr Warning: \headheight is too small (26.0pt): 
(fancyhdr)                Make it at least 117.41733pt, for example:
(fancyhdr)                \setlength{\headheight}{117.41733pt}.
(fancyhdr)                You might also make \topmargin smaller to compensate:

(fancyhdr)                \addtolength{\topmargin}{-91.41733pt}.

Comment: I did correct the warning but the table of contents is still removing the header and footer for some reason :/

Comment: there is lots of weird code here (the usual request is to post a minimal example with all unneeded code removed) but `\setlength\parskip{-2em}` ?????? I don't see how latex can ever make any reasonable output with such a setting.

Comment: `\usepackage{tocloft}` is the cause, you can simply remove it or if you need that package see section 2.2 of its manual on how to control the page style

Comment: I was about to give up and go back to Word lol. Thanks so much. Btw `\setlength\parskip{-2em}` gives me the space between paragraphs that I want. Is there a better way to set it?

Comment: it gives _negative!!!!!_ space. So every paragraph will over-print the paragraph above it. I have used TeX for 30 years and I think this is the first document I have seen with a negative parskip.

Comment: God bless you sir. Please provide the answer and I will gladly mark it as the correct one. As for the paragraph space, is there a better a for me to add a custom size to the gap?

Comment: take Peter's answer he wrote the package:-)

Comment: you can set parskip i just can not guess the intention of setting it negative so I can not suggest an alternative other than don't do that.

Comment: The intention was to have a smaller paragraph gap, the default is a bit too big for me :-)

Comment: the default paragraph spacing in `article` class is 0pt. I get the feeling that you hav eincluded dozens of lines of conflicting code from all over. If you have a large parskip you must have set it that way somewhere. but -2em doesnt reduce it by 2em it makes paragraphs over-print each other

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/126643/discussion-between-david-carlisle-and-manuel-bras).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use the `tocloft` package which sets the pagestyle for the initial ToC, etc., page  to `\tocloftpagestyle{<style>}` where `<style>` is one of the available page styles. The default is `\tocloftpagestyle{plain}`

Do `\renewcommand{\tocloftpagestyle}{<your page style>}`

Comment: Thank you sir. That did the trick. I need to clean up the packages because I'm not using most of them.